# How is the 40 character unique identifier in git generated? why is it unique?

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand why the 40 character identifier used in git is unique and is it foolproof.

Also what are the various inputs that are used to generate the unique key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an SHA-1 hash of some header information and the commit; see http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#object-details for details of the hashing, and http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#commit-object for the commit object being hashed.  It is not guaranteed to be unique (since it is created using a many-to-one mapping), but the probability of a collision are so small as to be practically zero.  You should treat the IDs as always unique.

Comment: "You should treat the IDs as always unique." The software certainly does. If there really are collisions in SHA-1 a lot of stuff will break.

Comment: Of course, for this to matter for git, it would have to be a collision within your own repo, so that is even less likely (it does not really have to be globally unique. Or maybe it does for folks like github who host many repos).